# Unable to install Guest additions in VBox 6.1

Tags: virtualbox

Linux newbie here. Host OS is Ubuntu 21.04. I want the Guest OS to be Kubuntu 21.04 but when I try to install Kubuntu into VBox, the screen is chopped off and I can’t resize it to see all the buttons to continue the install. See this https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQvBQ.jpg for all the details. It’s not letting me install Guest Additions.

How to fix this? I tried unmounting but that didn’t work.

These websites did not help. https://maheshhika.com/2012/09/28/virtual-box-verr_pdm_media_locked/ - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36500_01/E36502/html/qs-guest-additions.html -

Comment: I tried to follow you link for "all the details" but I couldn't read the tiny, blurry montage. My *guess* is that the virtual CD is already automatically mounted at `/media/<username>/` and you should just navigate there to run the installer.

Answer (score 1):

Kubuntu has a bug that prevents it from working on Virtual Box.

https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=407058

Solution is to try another distro. Issue resolved.